Prevent modal closure when using navigationMixin inside quick action modal for new record creation
I have an lwc with a button to create a new account using lightning NavigationMixin.
createAccountCmp.html
    <template>
         <lightning-button label="Create a New Account" onclick={createNewAccount}>/lightning-button>
   </template>

createAccountCmp.js
import {LightningElement,api} from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class createAccountCmp extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api recordId

    createNewAccount(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: {
                nooverride:'1',
                navigationLocation: "RELATED_LIST",
                recordTypeId:this.accountRecordTypeId
            }
        });
    }

}

This component is being utilized in a headless quick action using lightning modal.
screenActionDemo.html
<template>
    <lightning-modal-header label="My Modal Heading"></lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body>
        <template lwc:if={recordId}>
            <c-create-account-cmp record-id={recordId}></c-create-account-cmp>
        </template>

    </lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
    </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>

screenActionDemo.js
import {api} from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';

export default class screenActionDemo extends LightningModal  {

    @api content

    _recordId;

    @api
    get recordId() {
        return this._recordId;
    }

    set recordId(recordId) {
        if (recordId !== this._recordId) {
            this._recordId = recordId;
        }
    }
}

Upon clicking the create new account button, the quick action modal closes as soon as the url of the page changes and a new modal to create account record is opened.


